# Do public bitcoin nodes have a public page to view node data? And if so can one add additional information to it?

Tags: full-node

Do public bitcoin nodes have a public page to view public node data? Example is from monero public nodes: http://node.xmrbackb.one:28081/get_info -- it shows the node information.

Do Bitcoin public nodes have a public page that is accessible by the public? And if so, how can one add in additional values like for example a bitcoin address or an email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

Bitcoin nodes in general only speak the P2P protocol with the public, not HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Bitcoin Core and other available node software do not have any publicly accessible interface other than the P2P interface.

There are a few modified node software available to publicly expose statistics about the node. Some people may choose to install those software and would have information about their node exposed.